# How can I create this graphic?

Tags: diagrams, plot

The picture shows a normal linear regression.

Although it is easy to compute on paper, I have no idea how to code a linear regression in order to get an output shown as in the picture.

I would be very pleased if anyone could help me.

I have already tried {tikzpicture} etc. but it does not work out that good as pleased.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please edit your question and add a minimal example of what you tried.

Comment: `pgfplots` allows you to do this, see p 396 `Fitting Lines - Regression`: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots

Comment: `pstricks` (more precisely `pst-plot`) defines a `plotstyle=LSM`  for data files.

Comment: @CarLaTeX think a little before you get carried away! Rebecca wants to know `how she can create this graph`. If she knew, she wouldn't have asked that question.

Comment: @AndréC Rebecca wrote "I have already tried...". Did you read the entire post?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes, and her question is more general: she does not explicitly ask to correct her attempt made with `TikZ` or one of its descendants. She wants to know **which** packages allow her to do what she wants because she tagged `graphics` (and not `TikZ`). I told her `pgfplots`, Bernard told her `pstrics`.

Comment: @AndréC I don't think Rebecca wants an answer like "use this feature of this package", otherwise you should add an answer, not comments.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Let's wait a little while, we'll see who of us reads best in the crystal ball :-)

Comment: @AndréC Are you saying that a crystal ball is needed without an MWE? I'm happy to read you agree with me, eventually.

Comment: It would be good to improve the title of the question to say that it is a question of `building a normal linear regression`. Please modify this title to make the question easier to search with a search engine by clicking on the `edit` button.

Comment: Pleqee, edit the question title to reflect the inquiry of drawing a linear regression graph out of raw data. This will help future readers coming from relevant Google search results.

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [image: mwe]

With R and `knitr` this plot is relatively simple. However, the MWE is a bit complex to show automatically the actual coefficients (intercept, slope and error) as well as to place legend, arrow and label automatically, so one can change the  values *at some range* (for instance, the second y from 2 to -3) and still have a correct output in all aspects, even in the text out of the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

<<Daten,echo=F>>=
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,3,4,5),y=c(1,2,6,7,10,8))
@
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
<<Streudiagramm,echo=F,dev="tikz", fig.cap="Regressionszeile zeigt den Fehler $\\varepsilon_2$", fig.width=4.2, fig.height=3.5,fig.align='center',fig.pos="h">>=
par(mar=c(4,4,1,4)) # optional, just to crop
mod <- lm(df$y~df$x)
with(df,plot(x,y, pch=21, col="red",bg="yellow",ylim=c(min(df$y-.1),max(df$y+.1))))
abline(mod,col="blue",lwd=3)
legend(1, max(df$y), legend=c("$f(x_i)=\\beta_0+\\beta_1x_i$",
   paste("$y=",
         signif(mod$coefficients[1],3),"+",
         signif(mod$coefficients[2],3),"x$")),
       col=c("blue","white"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
arrows(df$x[2],df$y[2],df$x[2],predict(mod)[2], length=0.05, col =2, code=3)
text(df$x[2]+.1,mean(c(df$y[2],predict(mod)[2])),paste('Str\\"{o}erm: $\\varepsilon_i=y_i-f(x_i)$ =',signif(df$y[2]-predict(mod)[2],3)),adj=0)
@

Die Abbildung  \ref{fig:Streudiagramm} zeigt das  $\varepsilon_2 = 
\Sexpr{signif(df$y[2],3)} - 
\Sexpr{signif(predict(mod)[2],3)} =  
\Sexpr{signif(df$y[2]-(mod$coefficients[1]+(mod$coefficients[2]*df$x[2])),3)} $. 
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

Motivated by AndréC's comments... ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y 
1 2
2 2.5
3 6
3 6.5
4 10
5 8
}\datatable


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
        cells={anchor=west}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=north west,xmin=0,xmax=7,
ymin=0,ymax=15,enlargelimits=0.1]

    \addplot[only marks, mark=*] table[x=X,y=Y] {\datatable};
 \addlegendentry{$y_i$}

 \addplot[draw=none,color=red] table [
      x=X,
      y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}},
 ] {\datatable};
 \xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona}
 \xdef\offset{\pgfplotstableregressionb}
 \addplot[no marks,color=red,domain=-2:9] {\slope*x+\offset};
 \addlegendentry{$f(x_i)=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i$}
 \coordinate (aux1) at (2,{\slope*2+\offset});
 \coordinate (aux2) at (2,2.5);
\end{axis}
\draw[latex-latex,red] (aux1) -- (aux2)
node[midway,right,text=black,font=\sffamily]{St\"orterm:
$\varepsilon_i=y_i-f(x_i)$};
\marmot[xshift=8cm,whiskers,teeth,crystal ball]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this is motivated by Sebastiano's comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y 
1 2
2 2.5
3 6
3 6.5
4 10
5 8
}\datatable

% pgfmanual p. 1087
\pgfdeclareradialshading{ballshading}{\pgfpoint{-10bp}{10bp}}
 {color(0bp)=(cyan!15!white); color(9bp)=(cyan!75!white);
 color(18bp)=(cyan!70!black); color(25bp)=(cyan!50!black); color(50bp)=(black)}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{crystal ball}{\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0ex}{0ex}}{1ex}
  \pgfshadepath{ballshading}{0}
  \pgfusepath{}}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
        cells={anchor=west}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=north west,xmin=0,xmax=7,
ymin=0,ymax=15,enlargelimits=0.1]

    \addplot[only marks, mark=crystal ball,opacity=0.7] table[x=X,y=Y] {\datatable};
 \addlegendentry{$y_i$}

 \addplot[draw=none,color=red] table [
      x=X,
      y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}},
 ] {\datatable};
 \xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona}
 \xdef\offset{\pgfplotstableregressionb}
 \addplot[no marks,color=red,domain=-2:9] {\slope*x+\offset};
 \addlegendentry{$f(x_i)=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i$}
 \coordinate (aux1) at (2,{\slope*2+\offset});
 \coordinate (aux2) at (2,2.5);
\end{axis}
\draw[latex-latex,red] (aux1) -- (aux2)
node[midway,right,text=black,font=\sffamily]{St\"orterm:
$\varepsilon_i=y_i-f(x_i)$};
\marmot[xshift=8cm,whiskers,teeth,crystal ball]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off topic, but how did you make the little bear on the right hand side? It is very cute! :) Just another `tikzpicture`? In particular, how did roughly you make that ball with varying translucency?

Comment: @DanHoynoski Which *bear*??? Do you see a *bear* here? You can find bears [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzlings/tikzlings-doc.pdf), even with crystal balls (and indeed this is just a ball shading with some nontrivial opacity). But I insist that the "little bear" is a "cute marmot". ;-)

Comment: It would be good to improve the title of the question to say that it is a question of building a normal linear regression.

Comment: @AndréC I guess that is more a request to the OP. You may refer to [this question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7830/wouldnt-it-be-helpful-in-the-future-if-the-tikzperts-ask-the-ops-to-write-down) to motivate the request. (I won't do that as long as the OP does not confirm that this is what she's after.)

Comment: Until she has 50 reputation points, she can't answer the comments, in which case, the dialogue sear complicated, right?

Comment: @AndréC Yes, but this restriction does obviously not apply to you, does it? If you think it is worthwhile to ask her to change the title, you can do that, and do not need to involve me, right?

Comment: You responded by saying that my comments motivated you, you got involved on your own.  Changing the title will make the question easier to find with a search engine. So I devote myself and ask her the question myself....

Comment: @AndréC The OP can always comment on their own question

Comment: @marmot +1 for the crystal ball (and the examples as well). Just for the sake of my curiosity: how quickly do you create such graphs. Looks like 5 minutes and you're done.

Comment: @Dan Hoynoski. The marmot with crystal ball are inside the MWE…